# Image Location Property Of Picture Box

Tags: c#, winforms

How to set the Image Location Property of picture box in windows form design view ?

My folder Path : `bin/debug/images`

Answer (score 0):

you havae write this code

```
  pictureBox1.ImageLocation =Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "\\Images\\1.jpg");
 pictureBox1.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Images\\1.jpg");
```

then you have set the image in picture box